# set length of captured group

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to format the log of my server to be readable easily when I do a "tail -f".

My log look like :

```
{"item1":"ab","item2":"cdef","item3":"ghi"}
{"item1":"abc","item2":"defgh","item3":"i"}
```

I would like to obtain :

```
var1=ab__  | var2=cdef_ | var3=ghi
var1=abc_  | var2=defgh | var3=i__
```

Where '_' is a white space.

For now I use :

```
 sed -E 's/.*item1":"(.*)","item2":"(.*)","item3":"(.*)".*/var1=\1 | var2=\2 | var3=\3/'
```

And I get :

```
var1=ab | var2=cdef | var3=ghi
var1=abc | var2=defgh | var3=i
```

It is possible to set the length of captured group \1 \2 \3 ? Fill them with space or truncate them?

I would like to fix the length of each field ( fill or truncate ) and to stream my log in real time.

Comment: I suspect that `sed` may not be optimal for this. It seems like a job better suited to `awk`, but I don't know `awk`, so someone else will have to take this one up.

Comment: `jq` - which specialize in handling `json` data - may also be useful (not that much in order to obtain the desired format : it would only help selecting the properties AFAIK ; by default it pretty-prints and color-codes the JSON items though, which might be enough to make the log much more readable)

Comment: The issue that I see immediately is that if you want to space out column N to match the lengths of successive column Ns, you need to know the max length of column N.  But you don't know the max length until you've seen the whole file (which is antithetical to streaming with `tail -f`).  How can you know how much space to pad if you haven't seen the whole log?

Comment: If you just want to pad out to some fixed space (because you know the max column width a-priori, let us know what that is and please edit the question accordingly).  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I need to see my logs in real time and I would like to fix the length of my fields to an arbitrary length. It does not matter if they are filled or truncated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are already recommending `jq`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
$ jq -r '[(.item1, .item2, .item3)] | @tsv' log.json
ab      cdef    ghi
abc     defgh   i
```

<sup>*Note that the `@tsv` filter was introduced with `jq` version 1.5, so if you're on 1.4, perhaps it's time to upgrade.* :)</sup>

If you want the vertical bars, you can just add them within the array:

```
$ jq -r '[(.item1, "|", .item2, "|", .item3)] | @tsv' log.json
ab      |       cdef    |       ghi
abc     |       defgh   |       i
```

Note that `@tsv` adds a tab between every field, so this may not be exactly what you want.  It can, however, could easily be parsed by bash:

```
$ while IFS=$'\t' read one two three; do \
  printf 'var1=%-4s  | var2=%-5s | var3=%-4s\n' "$one" "$two" "$three"; \
  done < <(jq -r '[(.item1, .item2, .item3)] | @tsv' log.json)
var1=ab    | var2=cdef  | var3=ghi
var1=abc   | var2=defgh | var3=i
```

Or if the specific format isn't important and you just want things line up, perhaps this:

```
$ jq -r '[(.item1, "|", .item2, "|", .item3)] | @tsv' log.json | column -t
ab   |  cdef   |  ghi
abc  |  defgh  |  i
```

Of course, this doesn't handle `tail -f`, it just covers formatting. If you want to be able to process a *stream*, you will likely need to do that in a loop. For example:

```
tail -F "$logfile" | while read -r line; do
  jq -r '[(.item1, .item2, .item3)] | @tsv' <<< "$line" |
  while IFS=$'\t' read one two three; do
    printf 'var1=%-4s  | var2=%-5s | var3=%-4s\n' "$one" "$two" "$three"
  done
done
```

Note that the formatting option selected here is the `printf` one, because all the other solutions require knowledge of the maximum length of input data. With `printf`, we'll assume that you already know the maximum length, and have accounted for it in your format string.

Comment: I don't see how this can work given the constraint in the question on using `tail -f`.  If question asker wants to stream a log file they necessarily don't want to read all of the input.  Your last example deals with the stream, but it just chooses arbitrary values for the column widths (5,5,4), how do  you choose the column widths if you don't know the full input?

Comment: @JawguyChooser - That's exactly the point I made at the end of my answer. I chose the widths based on the sample output in the "*I would like to obtain*" part of the question. As I said in my answer, "we'll assume that you already know the maximum length".

Comment: I tried the last solution but I have the error 
`jq: error: tsv is not a valid format`

Comment: I have upgraded jq from v1.4 to v1.5 and it work fine.
thank you everyone.

Comment: @Zanifu, right, it didn't occur to me that `@tsv` wasn't part of 1.4. I've added a note to that effect. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Short **`jq`** + **`printf`** solution:

```
jq -rs '.[] |
@sh "printf \"var1=%-8s| var2=%-8s| var3=%-8s\n\" \(.item1) \(.item2) \(.item3)"' log | sh
```

The output:

```
var1=ab      | var2=cdef    | var3=ghi     
var1=abc     | var2=defgh   | var3=i
```

---

- `-s` - instead of running the filter for each *JSON* object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once
- `@sh` - the input is escaped suitable for use in a command-line for a *POSIX* shell

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Comment: Reading the entire input seems to miss the point if the question asker is using `tail -f`.

Comment: Yes, I don' t want to parse my entire file. I need to parse it in real time

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your sed output to `column -t` to make a table.

Comment: Though, of course, `tail -f` might break this.  Might be a way to do it two lines at a time... I dunno.